# 3D model in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, sprite-kit

We are building iPad application that uses football stadium 3D model. The screen should show the stadium in 3D and user should be able to rotate it.

The model has been successfully imported to Xcode (tried both .dae or .obj formats) and it works, but:

1) The rotation isn't smooth. Everything is very slow and discrete.

2) The application crashes from time to time admittedly due to memory usage issue. The application without this model uses 20 MB of memory and when the model is inserted – about 500 MB.

The size of the model is 50MB.

My guess is that model size (or detalization: too much polygons and textures) is an issue. I'm really not good in 3D stuff.

May someone advice if there is any way to reduce the file size not loosing in quality too much?

What model size should be considered as normal to be used in iOS applications?
Thanks in advance.